# What is the simplest way to create a NON-REST API in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, api, rest

There are debates about the pro's and con's of REST.
I personnaly don't need it in my project, and this topic is not to debate about the fact I actally need it ^^

Just note that I used Tastypie in a "REST mode" and decided to switch to a non-REST mode because my app is not CRUD based at all. My API is an *application API*, not a *user* API. In my case, using REST force me to do dirty and foolish things.

In my project, what I'd like to do can't be simpler:

- custom URL #1 executes some custom Django code
- custom URL #2 executes other custom Django code
- etc... That's it!

The only things I need are:

- GET and POST requests.
- when a user calls a URL, I want to know who is this user (request.user) or not authenticated. I use classic HTTP authentication.
- return results as JSON sothat my clients understand it.

The intrusive API stuff **I don't need** (but I am pretty forced to use it in a REST mode) are:

- Split logic by resources -> when a request need to deal with many models, splitted resources just drives me crazy to reach my goal.
- Authentication -> let me handle it myself with my Django code itself! My models actually DO know who can do what.

**So, How to create this non-REST api in a easy way? Which framework use?**
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would be creating your own views to handle the requests and then return JSON be too simple?

Comment: You have to create base class for CBV, which handle data and supports HTTP methods you need. For example, when you will do `POST`, you can get it from request and call `post()` method, defined in your class, which inherits base resource. Frameworks are too heavyweight for your purposes.

Comment: Hey @schillingt this is so simple that I didn't think about it at all :) It's actually clever... The two things to do by myself are to handle GET vs POST + JSON serialization. I guess both things are not complicated.

Comment: @coldmind Thanks for answering. However I don't know CBV well yet, but Im currently reading the doc to understand your answer better :)

Comment: @schillingt 1 just see one problem: how do you handle login in that case? I used classic HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering myself to the question:

I just found out that the creator of Tastypie made a second Python API framework named Restless.
Inspite of the name, it's still a Restfull framework, but the philosophy is very different from the former framework.

> *In building Tastypie, I tried to create something extremely complete & comprehensive. The result was writing a lot of hook methods (for easy extensibility) & a lot of (perceived) bloat, as I tried to accommodate for everything people might want/need in a flexible/overridable manner. But in reality, all I really ever personally want are the RESTful verbs, JSON serialization & the ability of override behavior.*

This framework lets you hardcode the behaviour of each REST methods (thank you!!!!).

The only thing now is to try to bypass the "REST behaviour" in an elegant way...

Answer (score 1):

There are method I used in my projects.
You have to define base resource:

```
class BaseResource(object):

    __METHODS = {
        'GET': 'get',
        'POST': 'post',
    }

    def __init__(self, methods):
        # here you look what allowed methods are in class init
        # and add it to self.methods

    def _process_body(self, request):
        request.data = None # here you will handle request and put json into variable

    def __call__(self, request, **kwargs):
        # here you look which method of view you must call

        if not request.method in self.methods:
            return HttpResponseNotAllowed(self.methods)

        attr = self.methods[request.method]
        func = getattr(self, attr, None)

        self._process_body(request)
        response = func(request, **kwargs)

        # here you can return response
```

And your view may look like this:

```
class SuppaView(BaseResource):
    def post(self, request):
        ...
```

Then in urls:

```
url('^your-cool-resource/$', views.SuppaView(methods=['POST'])),
```

You can decorate class methods as you need to add authorization and so on.

Comment: Thanks! It starts to be clearer to me. But let's say I will never use the same URL to make a GET or a POST. I mean I will have '^get-your-cool-resource/$' and '^post-your-cool-resource/$'. How would be the code in this way?

Comment: Actually, you can define both GET and POST in one class, but in urls you will have `url('^get-your-cool-resource/$', views.SuppaView(methods=['GET']))` and `url('^post-your-cool-resource/$', views.SuppaView(methods=['POST']))`